# jQuery document.ready strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox

we are trying to show a message inside a fancybox, on the page load event after the successful postback of a page. we are registering the script into the page using Page.RegisterClientScript method of ASP.NET.Here's the code in the .cs file :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Script", "ShowPopup('popup');", true);
```

Here's the javsacript function ShowPopup :

```
function showPopup(p) {
    ShowFancyBoxDiv("#divMessage", 50, 300);
}
```

But when we do this, only the first page in the view of the window is grayed-out and when scrolled down, the rest of the page is still active and ungrayed.

But when we add a timer ,as shown below, everything works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        ShowFancyBoxDiv("#divMessage", 50, 300);
        $("#fancybox-close").css("display", "none");
    }, 1000);
});
```

So, could anyone explain what is going on here. The document.ready should automatically check for the document to be fully loaded, then why do we need to use that timer function??? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you may still have elements loading, like images. Ready means the DOM is ready. It does not mean everything has been loaded as you state. If you want that then use `.load`.

```
$(window).load( function() {
   //code
} );
```

This website has a nice article on this vs ready.

http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/daily-tip-difference-between-document-ready-and-window-load-in-jquery/

Comment: DIDN'T WORK.
you meant something like : $(document).load( function() { ShowFancyBoxDiv("#divMessage", 50, 300); });

but when using this, don't know why but the ShowFancyBoxDiv() is not even fired???
Plus, even though I'm using a timeout of 1 sec, various elements of the page are still loading(when inspected through the 'net' tab of firebug), but still the fancybox appears properly. So, i believe, the problem must be something else.

Comment: @PratikChandra - Sorry, my code had an error in it. Try it now using $(window).load instead.

Comment: but still, what I don't get is, with a timer of 1 second, the images and other files are **still loading** but despite that, the fancy box is being loaded properly. So, if window.load waits for the images to load up before firing, a timer of 1 sec should not be able to solve the problem, right???

Comment: I think there is a difference between downloading/displaying the images and retrieving the image dimensions. I suspect that the image dimensions are retrieved almost immediately, which means that the browser engine can properly calculate element positioning before the full file has been obtained.

Comment: don't know why, but ummm...I just don't feel like believing this particular argument of yours. :)

Comment: This seems to be exactly what happens - http://jsfiddle.net/9zayy/1 . Even when a very large image is still loading its dimensions are known.